# Policy based access in database repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

Currently am I building a webapp, which should be very secure. This webapp exists of an Angular frontend, with a .NET Core backend. Auth0 is used for security, using their Lock product. To restrict access, Auth0 offers scopes. This scopes can be used in combination with Policy based access in .NET Core.

To restrict access, you can add `[Authorize("read:customers")]` for example, to allow users only if they have access to read customers. However, the Authorize attribute can only be used in the controllers.

Sometimes, it's happening that a user should have write access to orders, but orders are in that case also changing some data in another table the user should have no access to.

I was thinking to add authorization also in the repository. That the database changes should be happening only if their scope is correct for that action. Is this possible. Of course could I  add an if statement in every repository method, which checks the scopes from users, but is there a builtin attribute or function to verify if users have access to specific methods?

Comment: The repository layer should not be concerned with something like authorization. That's a separate concern, and an application layer concern at that. Also, what you're talking about is illogical. If a user can modify an order, and doing so modifies something else, the user *must* also have the right to modify that. If that's not the case, then they should not have access to modify orders.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point indeed. I use the onion structure, so my structure is layered, so maybe this isn't a good idea. Good point also that it should be used, independent for that rights. You're right.